# when we create an xml file, where is the line that implements the xsd file?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd-1.1

im new to xml i have a questions:
when we create an xml file, where is the line that implements the xsd file?
i mean how we get the reference to an XML Schema ,i dont understand 
there is no line in xml defines the location of the xml schema in my local computer ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<note
xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xsd">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema doesn't exist on your local computer. It exists at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xsd.

Comment: what if i don't have internet connection ,i can't edit the file anymore?

Comment: Why would you need the schema in order to edit the file?

Comment: to respect the XML grammar so that the XML file makes sense right!!?

Comment: You can do that without having immediate access to the schema.

Comment: In all XML courses, they say that namespaces provide a method for avoiding element name conflicts.
but it's not the only use of it, it gave us the location of the schema resource to download when the XML file is interpreted right?

Comment: No. The namespace name uses URL syntax for uniqueness, there is no defined requirement for the document it points to to be anything in particular (or exist at all).

Comment: How does the xml file know the roles of the schema then?!
i didn't understand how this works do you have any good xml course ?

Comment: The XML file doesn't. Only tools which especially use schema know about the schema. Read their documentation to learn what mechanism they use to access it.